# How to select multiple text parts with Scrapy inside of a tag with subtags?

Tags: python, xpath, scrapy

I have this sample-html:

```
<div class="classname1">
  "This is text inside of" 
  <b>"a subtag"</b>
  "I would like to select."
  <br>
  "More text I don't need"
  </br>
  
  (more br and b tags on the same level)

</div>
```

The result should be a list containing:

```
["This is text inside of a subtag I would like to select."]
```

I tried:

```
response.xpath('//div[@class="classname1"]//text()[1]').getall()
```

but this gives me only the first part "This is text inside".

There are two challenges:

1. Sometimes there is no b tag
2. There is even more text after the desired section that should be expluded

Maybe a loop?
If anyone has an approach it would be really helpful.

Answer (score 1):

What about this (used `More text I don't need` as a stopword):

```
parts = []
for text in response.xpath('//div[@class="classname1"]//text()').getall():
    if 'More text I don't need' in text:
        break
    parts.append(text)
result = ' '.join(parts)
```

**UPDATE** For example, you need to extract all text before `Ort:` :

```
def parse(self, response):
    for card_node in response.xpath('//div[@class="col-md-8 col-sm-12 card-place-container"]'):
        parts = []
        for text in card_node.xpath('.//text()').getall():
            if 'Ort: ' in text:
                break
            parts.append(text)
        before_ort = '\n'.join(parts)
        print(before_ort)
```

Comment: response.xpath('//div[@class="col-md-8 col-sm-12 card-place-container"]//text()').getall() gives me a result for page https://ausschreibungen-deutschland.de/Berlin but when using if 'Offizielle Bezeichnung' in text, the result variable is empty.

Answer (score 0):

Use the descendant or self xpath selector in combination with the position selector as below

```py
response.xpath('//div[@class="classname1"]/descendant-or-self::*/text()[position() <3]').getall()
```

Comment: Your solution gives me all text elements including "More text I don't need" but I only need the first three. Sometimes there is no b-Tag, so extracting the first element would be enough. I am thinking about a loop checking the first three elements or similar.

Comment: See the edit to my answer

Comment: I appreciate your work and it seems it's almost complete but I am still receiving more than 3 results. Maybe I should show you the site. It's https://ausschreibungen-deutschland.de/Berlin and the part I would like to scrape is "Offizielle Bezeichnung: Berliner Wasserbetriebe" but it consists of 3 parts that are interrupted by a b tag (but this is not always the case).